# How to change page title dynamically in Sveltekit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm learning SvelteKit and this might be a very elementary question. But I could not figure out how to change the tab's title.

In my `src/+layout.svelte` I have:

```
    <script>
        let title="My Site Homepage"
    
    </script>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        ...
      <title>{title}</title>
  
   </head>
```

Then in my `/src/faq/+page.svelte` I'd like to change the title to 'FAQ'

So I put

```
<script>
    let title="FAQ"        
</script>
```

But when I visit `http://localhost:5173/faq` the tab's title is not changed.
So I'm wondering how can I do that? Is there an idomatic way to do so?

Comment: If you want to enforce a certain format for titles (like `Page title | Website name`) and not want to add the second bit every page you could [use a store](https://svelte.dev/repl/b604a75a8a344527a39f10cab7b7ee66?version=3.32.0). If you just need to change the title based on what happens in the page you can just use a variable for that page.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well, thanks svelte [docs](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-head), I found my answer.

> The svelte:head element allows you to insert elements inside the
> `<head>` of your document:

So I just need to add this to FAQ page:

```
<svelte:head>
    <title>FAQ</title> 
</svelte:head>
```

Comment: I think you also need `%sveltekit.head%` in your `app.html` file, but any scaffolding should have already done that for you

Answer (score 7):

From my understanding you want to change the title as go.

To get this I don't suggest using two way binding, since 'variable' you are inputting to bind is not actually a variable but a space box which is functioned for binding.
Just pass the title and it might work.

Since people need direct answers instead of explaining the issues.

```
//../components/meta-title.svelte

<svelte:head>
   <title>{title}</title>
</svelte:head>

<script>
   export let title = "default title for page"
</script>


//../pages/_layout.svelte

<Meta title="This is a dynamic title" />
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Thank you