# Svelte SEO - Dynamic page title

Tags: dynamic, seo, svelte, sveltekit, page-title

First off, I have already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74243719/how-to-change-page-title-dynamically-in-sveltekit), but it does not really answer my own question.

Here is my situation:

- I have a main page (+page.svelte, in the same folder as +layout.svelte) and a few extra pages (+page.svelte, located in subfolders);
- +layout.svelte uses [SvelteSEO](https://github.com/artiebits/svelte-seo) which contains a number of tags, including a "title" tag which is currently a simple string;
- I have already tweaked SvelteSEO by using {$page.url.pathname} to make the "canonical" tag dynamic (it's set to: "https://example.com{$page.url.pathname}") and it works well when I deploy.

What I want to do now is tweak the "title" tag to make it dynamic, so that each page would be something like "Example | Page title".

What I have tried:

- Adding "export let title = "Example | Page title X" to the script of page X;
- Adding "import { title } from 'path to Page X'" in +layout.svelte;
- Using the "title" tag in the SvelteSEO part of +layout.svelte.

However, that's not working and I am not sure what I can do.
Spoiler: I am still a bit of a noob and I am mostly tweaking a website that was designed by a developer, so I still have a lot to learn!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for stores https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store

Comment: Thanks @yongjulee. Could you be a little more specific about the implementation? Do I have to create a store? Do I just need to assign "title" to an existing store? How does this work?

Comment: This basically works by storing the "title" value to store, and referencing it globally in +layout.svelte. It's reactive. If you change it anywhere in the page, or layout, you get that updated value. It's a bit hard to avoid stores when it comes to this SEO scenario. If you want to avoid it, I am not sure if there's any better way without using a database.

Comment: Thanks @yongjulee. I don't necessarily want to avoid it, I want to make sure I do it right. I saw there was already a store referred to, so I went there and added "export const page_title = writable("title_example");". Then, I imported page_title in my layout.svelte and I see it appear in svelteseo. However, adding "export let titlepage = "Example | Page" to the script of page.svelte does not change anything.

Comment: I guess you should read the docs thoroughly as something went wrong when you added the ```export let title_page =""``` in your ```+page.svelte``` You should update it in that page, or anywhere you want to have a updated value for the page title, so the page_title in your +layout.svelte has that updated value. Also, in Svelte, there's a difference between calling a store by $page_title, or page_title. The former represents a reactive value, which you should add in +layout.svelte. You can try that on your end, to check the mechanism of both.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more digging and it half works. I now have my import and svelteseo in layout.svelte, and I have import and "page_title.set("Example | Page");" in each page.svelte file. However, the page title only updates when the page is refreshed, not when a page is loaded via the hamburger menu. Any ideas to force the change in that situation?

Comment: The ```{#key} block``` may come in handy to update the whole meta tags, and title whenever the change is made. https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#key You should wrap those tags that need to be updated whenever the reactive store variable gets updated. As you are using SvelteSEO, try wrapping it in a key block. Also, since we are talking about SEO, you should check the page source too. It may look like it is changed, but it may not in the source.

Comment: Can you let me know how exactly you assigned the key block? ```{#key $page_title}{/key}``` should reload the whole component unless the title_tag is not reactive. I can't see how it is going on unless I see the real code. Also, since the ```<title>``` is not a component, there's no need for a key block. I apologize I guess my words were misleading. Anyways, the basic approach is simple. 1. You put the ```<svelte-seo/>``` component in your layout with store variables 2. Wrap this by ```{#key} block``` 3. Update the $store from a child component like +page.svelte.

Comment: Wow, I made a whole copy-paste of all relevant documents in a pastebin to show that I had done as you had said but that it was not working, but now it does seem to be working. I'll check again later but it seems good. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. I've encountered similar issues before. It may be better off to handle it page by page as SEO can be a bit complex especially for the website with lots of articles, and those that utilize schema.org a lot. Also, for a code readability, I am sure you'd find stores a lot helpful. Keep up the good work there!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set the title dynamically inside `+layout.svelte` based on the `$page.url.pathname` and a 'lookup' function or object

```
<script>
    import {page} from '$app/stores'
    import SvelteSeo from "svelte-seo";

    function getPageTitle(pathname) {
        switch(pathname) {
            case '/' :
                return 'Home'
            case '/about':
                return 'About'
            default:
                return 'Default title'
        }
    }
</script>

<SvelteSeo
    title={getPageTitle($page.url.pathname)}
    ...
    />
```

```
<script>
    import {page} from '$app/stores'
    import SvelteSeo from "svelte-seo";

    const pageTitle = {
        '/' :   'Home',
        '/about': 'About',
    }
</script>

<SvelteSeo
    title={pageTitle[$page.url.pathname] ?? 'Default title'}
    ...
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there an advantage to do this over using stores, as proposed by @yongjulee? A slight disadvantage I see here is that you need to remember to update this whenever you add a page or change the title. With the store process, everything stays in the page, which is more convenient.

Comment: @KenMatsuo When creating a route and corresponding page file, you also have to remember to add the title info / set the title store. If you want to check, that all pages have a title set, you'd have to go through all files. I would prefer to have all the information in one place. Also given the case the title should get another prefix or a character like the `|` in your example should change, that would be an easy adjustment.

Comment: I guess to each their own. The way I set it up, the fixed part ("Example.com |") is in the layout file and can be changed at once for all pages. Then, if I create a new page, I'm likely to just copy-paste an existing one and then amend it, including by updating the title, so all I need to do is change a single page. But thanks for suggesting this and I remain open to it in case there are other benefits.